# $x^TMx \geq \lambda_{min}x^Tx$ is true?

Tags: linear-algebra

Is it true that:

$$x^TMx \geq \lambda_{min}x^Tx\;?$$

Let us assume that $M$ is positive definite.

Comment: The answer is yes: this is a consequence of [Rayleigh's theorem, as explained here](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Rayleigh_quotient)

Answer (score 1):

All eigenvalues of $M$ are positive since $M$ is positive semidefinite. Let $0 < \lambda_1\leq \dots \leq \lambda_n$. Also $M$ is nonsingular.

Let $f_1,\dots,f_n$ be the eigenvectors of $M$. These span the space. So $\exists \beta_1,\dots,\beta_n$ such that $\sum_i \beta_i f_i = x$.

$$x^T M x = x^T (M x) = x^T (\sum_i \beta_i \lambda_i f_i)$$
Expand the brackets. Let $\geq$ mean that all components are larger than the previous.
$$Mx =\sum_i \beta_i \lambda_i f_i \geq \lambda_1 \sum_i \beta_i f_i = \lambda_1 x$$
Substitute $Mx \geq \lambda_1 x$ in the original statement.
$$x^T M x \geq \lambda_1 x^T x$$

Comment: It's a bit weird to use your order on the matrix, is it not? On a diagonalisation basis, $\frac{x^T M x}{x^T x} = \sum \lambda_i \frac{x_i^2}{\sum x_i^2}$ is a convex combination of all the $\lambda_i$, so it's larger than the smallest one. And, by the way, the positivity of the $\lambda_i$'s is irrelevant.

Comment: Yes, indeed it uses only the fact that the matrix is diagonalizable. See Raleigh Quotient

Comment: The inequality $Mx\geq \lambda_1x$ cannot be true for all vectors $x$. If it were, you could apply this to $-x$ and conclude....

Comment: @sinbadh in fact, the theorem depends on the fact that $M$ is *unitarily* (or orthogonally) diagonalizable.