# Is there an inequality for $x^TMx$ that uses all the eigenvalues?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $M$ is a positive definite matrix, [we know that](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1700202/xtmx-geq-lambda-minxtx-is-true)

$$x^TMx \geq \lambda_{min}x^Tx$$

Is there another similar inequality that takes into account all the eigenvalues of $M$?

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Apologies. Fixed now.

Comment: Writing $\lambda_{\min}$ takes into account all the eigenvalues, and you cannot hope for a better inequality.

Comment: @ChristianBlatter Oh that's very interesting. Thank you.   The bound is not always tight however so I was hopeful that there might be some ways to make it tighter in those cases.

Comment: To support @ChristianBlatter's comment: note that is bound is tight when $x$ is the eigenvector associated to $\lambda_{\min}$.

Comment: @Surb This is true but it is not tight in other cases so a better overall bound would seem possible at first sight.

Comment: If you want to involve all the eigenvalues, I think, not to an inequality but to an equality : the Rayleigh quotient $\dfrac{x^TMx}{x^Tx}$ for any $x$ is a weighted average with positive values of all the $\lambda_i$s...

Comment: I hope this isn't inappropriate, but it would be great if someone could write a proper answer to the linked question too. The current answer is not quite correct as mentioned in the comments.

Comment: @JeanMarie If I understand the Rayleigh quotient you need to know the eigenvectors too. If so, I was looking for an inequality only involving the eigenvalues.